# how the binding of const type works in c++?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

why this binding is ok

```
int main()
{
    double d = 4.56;
    const int &r = d;

    return 0;
}
```

but this is not

```
int main()
{
    double d = 4.56;
    int &r = d;

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone explain me while the first one compile but second one shows error

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to a converted type (the `double` has to be converted to an `int`), you get a prvalue, since the converted `int` is a temporary with no address in memory. Therefore, binding a regular reference to it doesn't work, because they can only bind to glvalues. `const` type references can bind to prvalues, so the first one compiles still. Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Answer (score 1):

An `int` reference cannot be bound to an object of type `double`, because the types mismatch.

So in order to make the initialization of the reference work at all, a new temporary object of the correct type `int` must be created. This is possible because there is an implicit conversion sequence from `double` to `int`.

The reference should then bind to this temporary, i.e. to a rvalue expression, but only `const` lvalue references are allowed to bind to rvalues. Non-`const` lvalue references are not allowed to do that, making the second program ill-formed.

Note that in the first program, although the reference is bound to a temporary object that would usually be destroyed at the end of the full-expression that it was created in, binding to a reference extends the lifetime of that temporary object to the lifetime of the reference. So using `r` in the first program is actually ok.

However, access through `r` will not refer to `d`, but to that new temporary object that is independent of `d`, which may be surprising, and therefore I think it is not a good idea to write like that. Use `auto&` or `const auto&` to make sure that `r` will certainly refer to `d` and that there is never any implicit conversion happening due to a type mismatch. If you want the conversion, just use `int` instead of a reference to `int`.

Comment: why after the implicit conversion the result is rvalue . I mean when double to int conversion takes place why d converts to rvalue int why not a lvalue int

Comment: @S.M.TusharIbneSalam Because expressions designating temporaries are always rvalues. It would not be consistent with the rest of the language to have it be different here. It you write `const int &r = static_cast<int>(d);` explicitly, then `static_cast<int>(d)` is also a rvalue.